# BeginInvoke on explicit interface member

Tags: c#, .net, compact-framework, begininvoke

With a "classic" method implementation, I usually perform BeginInvoke like this:

```
private delegate void FooDelegate();
public void Foo()
{
  if(InvokeRequired)
  {
    BeginInvoke(new FooDelegate(Foo));
    return;
  }

  // Do what you want here
}
```

How to do the same thing when the method is an explicit interface member declaration? Like:

```
public void IFace.Foo()
{
  // Need to BeginInvoke here
}
```

This does not work:

```
private delegate void FooDelegate();
public void IFace.Foo()
{
  if(InvokeRequired)
  {
    BeginInvoke(new FooDelegate(IFace.Foo));
    return;
  }

  // Do what you want here
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to cast `this` to `IFace` first:

```
var iface = (IFace)this;
BeginInvoke(new FooDelegate(iface.Foo));
```

Answer (score 0):

Because your implementation is [explicit](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288461%28v=vs.71%29.aspx), the method Foo cannot be accessed via the class instance. Only via the interface instance. This means you need to cast your instance `this` to an `IFace` instance. Then you can pass that method to `BeginInvoke`:

```
var asIFace = (IFace)this;
BeginInvoke(asIFace.Foo));
```